# JSON Serializer for arbitrary HashMaps in Voldemort

Tags: java, json, hashmap, voldemort

I am trying to set up the configuration for Voldemort key-value store. Now, I'd like to be able to store arbitrary hashmaps in it, but I haven't found the way to do so (or if it is possible).

According to the documentation I should use this syntax:

```
{"fname":"string", "lname":"string", "id":"int32", "emails":["string"]}
```

To indicate that I want to store a HashMap representation of a Java bean, but with constraints on allowed keys (only `fname`,`lname`,`id` and `emails`) and their types.

What I would need is to be able to store an arbitrary map like this:

```
{"name":"fred", "id":15}
```

or like this:

```
{"apples":"50$", "oranges":"15€"}
```

(Map values are meaningless, just an illustration of maps with different key names, and value types)

Is there a way to define a schema that would accept an arbitrary hashmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have found useful is to just use generic raw storage (where byte[] is passed), and pre-serializing things on client side. This is trivial to use (I use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org)):

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  // to store:
  byte[] data = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(myMap);
  // and when retrieving back:
  Map<String,Object> data = mapper.readValue(data, Map.class);
```

While Voldemort does support its "JSON-like" storage (it's not JSON but simple binary dictionaries, as far as I know), there isn't much benefit to using it in my opinion, since you can not query on it or request subsets of document.

Comment: This seems quite straightforward. Just to make sure - this `byte[]` is a JSON string representation, not a serialized Java object, right?

Comment: We are probably using different versions of of Jackson. In 1.6.3 `writeValueAsString` returns a `String`, and `readValue` for `byte[]` has some extra params. Anyway, I tried your approach and it works like a charm! Thanks..

Comment: Ah, my bad -- it should be "writeValueAsBytes()" instead. Glad to hear it works; this is a common use case, although I haven't used it with V myself yet.